# Extract column names as a variable

Tags: r

Is there a way to get row information as a character like shown below

as is below

```
iris[2,]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
2          4.9           3          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Expected output

```
iris[2,]
"Sepal.Length = 2 , Sepal.Width = 4.9, Petal.Length = 1.4, Petal.Width = 0.2, Species = 'setosa'"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> paste0(colnames(iris),"=",iris[2,],collapse=", ")
[1] "Sepal.Length=4.9, Sepal.Width=3, Petal.Length=1.4, Petal.Width=0.2, Species=1"
```

**Edit:** if you really want it in your specific format, you will need to modify the data a little bit, that is all the factors need to be converted to strings and padded with a single quote.

```
> iris$Species=paste0("'",as.character(iris$Species),"'")
> paste0(colnames(iris),"=",iris[2,],collapse=", ")
[1] "Sepal.Length=4.9, Sepal.Width=3, Petal.Length=1.4, Petal.Width=0.2, Species='setosa'"
```

Comment: Thanks. But species is coming as 1 ? Not possible to make is 'setosa'?

Comment: @arunaaib That is an issue with factors, a workaround is to convert factors to regular strings, then it will work.